# Showing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Since $\sqrt[3]{2}, i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$, their product $\sqrt[3]{2}i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$, which implies $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$. However, I am told that this is a tricky question. I have stared at this question for a while but still cannot figure out where the tricky part is? Can someone point it out to me? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It seems that there is a typo in the book and the tricky part is showing the inclusion is the other way around, i.e. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)$.

My thoughts: Since $(\sqrt[3]{2}i)^3 = -2i$, $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)$. So $\sqrt[3]{2} = (1/i)\cdot \sqrt[3]{2}i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)$. So $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)$. Since it is clear that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i)$. The two fields are actually equal.

Comment: Doesn't seem tricky to me, unless they want you to show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)\not\supset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i)$ or $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2i})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i)$

Comment: @student91 Indeed I want to show $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)\not\supset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i)$. Is there a concise way of showing this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @StinkingBishop I am new to abstract algebra and not familiar with the concept of a degree of a field extension. Is it possible to show strict inclusion by showing that there is an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i)$ that's not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Does $(\sqrt[3]{2}i)^3 = -2i$ imply $i \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)$? Sorry for the confusion as I am new to abstract algebra.

Comment: Ehr; there were some errors in my comment, sorry. Yes; I think some of the comments above are not quite right, either.

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics Yes, since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} i)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$, and both $-2i$ and $-2$ are in that subfield, then their quotient must be in that subfield also.  (And then, since both $\sqrt[3]{2} i$ and $i$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} i)$, their quotient $\sqrt[3]{2}$ is also in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} i)$.  From that, it follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}, i) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2} i)$, so the inclusion you asked about is in fact *not* strict.)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I should have checked the comment - sorry.

Comment: @DanielSchepler I see. So in fact the fields are equal. Thank you so much for your comment!

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't know what I was thinking. Deleted the wrong comment,

Comment: @StinkingBishop: Same thing I was thinking on first readthrough...

Answer (score 1):

It seems not so clear why this is a "tricky" question. Perhaps the following question was intended (but
of course I cannot say):

*Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+i)$.*

This question is quite a popular question, so it has been solved here a few times, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4638214/mathbbq-sqrt32-i-mathbbq-sqrt32-i), or here:

[How can I prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+i)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967060/how-can-i-prove-that-mathbbq-sqrt32-i-mathbbq-sqrt32i)

Edit: Another possibility is to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},i)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}i)$, and furthermore, that
$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},\omega)\supsetneq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega)$, arising by the splitting field of $X^3-2$.