# Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2)\sqrt[3](5) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{5})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2)\sqrt[3](5)) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{5})$?

I've tried writing any element $x \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(2)\sqrt[3](5)$ with $x = a + b\sqrt(2)\sqrt[3](5)$ in terms of $a + b(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{5})$, but I can't find a way. Anyone know how to approach this?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Formatting note:  type `\sqrt{5}` or `\sqrt5` rather than `\sqrt(5)`

Comment: This has been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8409/degree-of-sqrt2-sqrt35-over-mathbbq-sqrt2-and-mathbbq-sq?rq=1), in the comments.

Comment: Use the method described in the accepted answer for this question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967060/how-can-i-prove-that-mathbbq-sqrt32-i-mathbbq-sqrt32i?rq=1  Try to adapt it to your problem, and if you get stuck, show your work here and we can resolve your issue.